# Search using LIKE behaviour

Tags: api, search, mendeley

I'm using the Mendeley API and when I search documents (using the /search/documents) I can specify a query parameter that search string in any fileds.

Now it seems that the Mendeley applies a strict match on the string.
For example if I have a document having the string "research" in the title, when I search using the query="resea" they return nothing.

Is it possible to search using a sort of LIKE?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Their documentation is not much detailed, and sometimes appears even conflicting (I was not able to implement the advanced search operators indicated [here](https://dev.mendeley.com/code/core_quick_start_guides.html), for example)... but I have tried some searches using '`*`' like `query="resea*"` in your case, and it returns a bigger amount of data than the original world, so, I believe it works...